# Select date ranges with a 50% overlap to another date range

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a series of date ranges with columns e.g.
start_date, end_date, period_name

```
   1         100     Roman
 -50          75     Iron Age b
-100          20     Iron Age a
```

My team have asked me to build 2 queries:

1. Select the Roman period and any which overlaps
2. same as 1 but only those ranges which overlap >40%

I'm assuming I would have to write a function in postgresql (PL/pgSQL), any help is very welcome.

Comment: Related answer on SO: [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305292/939860). Your table definition showing data types and constraints and your Postgres version would be instrumental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be expressed using Postgres' [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) quite nicely

First query: find all ages that overlap with the Roman age:

```
select *
from ages a1
where period_name <> 'Roman'
  and exists (select *
              from ages a2
              where period_name = 'Roman' 
                and int4range(a1.start_date, a1.end_date) && int4range(a2.start_date, a2.end_date))
```

For the second one it's necessary to calculate the length of the overlap, this can be done using the [intersection operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) for ranges: `*`, e.g. `int4range(0,100,'[]') * int4range(-50,75,'[]')` yields 76. This result has to be compared to the total length of the Roman age to get the percentage.

As this requires access to both ages (the roman and the overlapping) at the same time, this is better done using a join.

To make the final query easier to read, I use [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to turn the two columns into a proper range, then I use that to make the join.

Once I have that. the overlapping percentage is easy to calculate:

```
with ranges as (
   select period_name, 
          int4range(start_date, end_date, '[]') as period,
          upper(int4range(start_date, end_date, '[]')) - lower(int4range(start_date, end_date, '[]')) as years
   from ages
), overlapping as (
  select o.period_name as overlapping_period_name, 
         r.period as roman_period, 
         o.period as overlapping_period, 
         r.period * o.period as overlap_length, 
         r.years as roman_years, 
         o.years as other_yers
  from ranges r
    join ranges o on r.period && o.period and o.period_name <> 'Roman'
  where r.period_name = 'Roman'
)
select overlapping_period_name, 
       overlapping_period,
       (upper(overlap_length) - lower(overlap_length))::numeric / roman_years as overlap_percent
from overlapping;
```

The cast `::numeric` is needed because otherwise it would be an integer division and the result would be `0` not `0.75`

To display only those with a minimum of 40% overlap just add a where condition:

```
.... 
select *
from overlapping
where (upper(overlap_length) - lower(overlap_length))::numeric / roman_years >= 0.4
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/JIOAV33074

---

If you need to do a lot of calculations on the "periods", it might be a good idea to store them as a range directly, that saves a lot of converting back and forth when doing calculations.

Comment: One more reason for using `date`: There is no year `0`. From 1st Jan (-5 BC) up to 1st Jan (5 AD) it's 9 years, not 10! The calculations - if they use integers - have to be adjusted, if we want to be accurate. With dates, it would be done without hassle.

Comment: I don't think the archaeologists would add up the years, especially since they are assigned to a period name which is the more common shorthand. The purpose for allowing the selection of period names which have a n% overlap is so they can achieve some kind of fuzzy period search. If they do count the years, they'll have to remember to subtract 1 from the result, I'll add it to their manual.